# Complement of codimension 1 subset of affine scheme not affine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Noetherian integral affine scheme. Let $U\subset X$ be an open subscheme whose complement has irreducible components of codimension $1$. Is $U$ affine?

Some remarks:

- By EGA 4, Cor. 21.12.7, the complement of a codimension 2 closed subset is not affine.
- if $X$ is the spectrum of a UFD, then I believe this can not happen. The ideal defining the complement has height 1. Thus the radical has height 1, so it is an intersection of prime ideals of height 1 so it is principal.
- if $X$ is of Krull dimension 1 (e.g. Dedekind domain), this can [not](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09N9) happen.

Comment: [This note by Ravi Vakil](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nonfg.pdf) gives an example of an affine variety $Z$ having an open set $Y$ with complement of codimension $1$ and such that the ring of global sections on $Y$ is not noetherian, and in particular, $Y$ is not affine.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen in the note it is stated that the algebra of global sections is not finitely generated. How does it follow that it is not Noetherian? For example, $k[[x]]$ is not finitely generated but it is Noetherian. Could you clarify?

Comment: Ah yes, there are various presentations of this counterexample. In [Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), exercise 19.11.H, the same example is given and it is stated that it is not noetherian… I'm afraid I can't remember why just now. On the other hand [this note by Ojanguren](http://sma.epfl.ch/~ojangure/nichtnoethersch.pdf) (in French) gives a simpler example, with a proof of non-noetherianness… but without the assumption of integrality.

Comment: It may be worth asking the question under what conditions the converse of the implication “finite type ⇒ noetherian” holds. I realize I don't know whether a subalgebra of $k[t_1,\ldots,t_d]$ can be noetherian without being of finite type, for example.

Comment: FWIW, the user appears to have been part of a group of accounts controlled by the same individual

Comment: An example of a quasiaffine variety whose ring of global functions is not finitely generated follows already from the paper: Bernšteĭn, I. N.; Gelʹfand, I. M.; Gelʹfand, S. I. Differential operators on a cubic cone.(Russian) Uspehi Mat. Nauk27(1972), no.1, 185–190, much earlier than Vakil's note referenced above. [I am not sure if this is related to the original question, this is a comment on the above comment, hope it's not out of place].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406384) by Roth and Vakil ($\mathrm{cd}$ stands for cohomological dimension):

> Let $S$ be $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at a point, and let $X$ be the
>   affine cone over some projective embedding of $S$. Let $Z\subset X$ be
>   the affine cone over the exceptional divisor of the blowup. Then $Z$
>   is of codimension one in $X$, but $\mathrm{cd}(X\backslash Z) = 1$, so
>   in particular it is not affine. This shows that, conversely, the
>   complement of a Weil divisor in an affine scheme need not be affine...

Note that the complement of an effective Cartier divisor in an irreducible affine scheme *is* affine so if in addition to the assumptions in the question the ambient scheme is factorial ([e.g. regular](https://justinsmath.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/regular-implies-locally-factorial/)), then the complement of any pure codimension 1 closed subset is affine.